# Python generator doesn't iterate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do a tree traversal but the problem is the yield returns a generator object but I am not able to iterate the generator object. I am very new to python, so any help will be appreciated.

```
def inorder_keys(self):
    try:
        if self.flag:
            self.head = self.root
            self.head_key = self.root_key
            self.flag = False
        if self.head.left is not None:
            self.head_key = self.head.left
            self.head = self.dict_of_keys[self.head_key]
            BinarySearchTreeDict.inorder_keys(self)
        else:
            yield self.head_key
            yield self.head.parent
            #print(self.head_key)
            #print(self.head.parent)
            temp = self.head.parent
            self.head = self.dict_of_keys[temp]
            self.head = self.dict_of_keys[self.head.right]
            BinarySearchTreeDict.inorder_keys(self)
    except KeyError:
        self.flag = True
    pass



try:
    x = object01.inorder_keys()
    print(''.join(x))
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Output:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "...\output.py"
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: without seeing the object itself so I'm unsure, my guess is you want `for x in BinarySearchTreeDict.inorder_keys(self): yield x` (in two places)

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your suggestion.

Comment: I think you are very well iterating over your generator but the code for your generator is buggy and doesn't return what you are hoping for. If you want help for debugging you need to provide explanations for your logic and a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your data structure seems awfully weird to me, but here is the general pattern that you want to use:

```
def inorder_keys(self):
    if self.head.left is not None:
        yield from self.head.left.inorder_keys()
    yield self.head_key
    if self.head.right is not None:
        yield from self.head.right.inorder_keys()
```

And that’s it if I am understanding your data structure correctly.

Comment: Thanks. This did help. I didn't know there existed a "yield from" keyword. I would have used Java, but it's mandatory that I submit my assignment in python, hence the whole question.